# Filter unique values from a JSON

Tags: angularjs, filter, unique, unique-key, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs for my page. I want to filter the values from the JSON object, So that no redundancy exists. But I didn't find any way to get the unique values from angular ng-repeat. Is there anyway to do that?

Ok, Here is some description about the question. I have a JSON in this format. This JSON I am getting from a service. So we cant expect how the repeated data occure.

```
result = [
        {
            _id: "500004",
            subject: "Complete the task",
            date: "25 Aug, 2013"
        },      
        {
            _id: "500004",
            subject: "Complete the task",
            date: "25 Aug, 2013"
        },      
        {
            _id: "500005",
            subject: "Attend to the event",
            date: "2 Jan, 2013"
        },      
        {
            _id: "500065",
            subject: "Some task deadline",
            date: "20 Sep, 2013"
        },      
        {
            _id: "500004",
            subject: "Complete the task",
            date: "25 Aug, 2013"
        }
]
```

I want the output JSON to be with no repeated elements, So that my output will be something like this

```
result = [
        {
            _id: "500004",
            subject: "Complete the task",
            date: "25 Aug, 2013"
        },      
        {
            _id: "500005",
            subject: "Attend to the event",
            date: "2 Jan, 2013"
        },      
        {
            _id: "500065",
            subject: "Some task deadline",
            date: "20 Sep, 2013"
        }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? Your question is too vague... Provide code and also mention what is your expected output...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make use of Angular UI which has the `unique` filter defined.

The source can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js).

Basically, you can then make use of the filter as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result | unique:'_id'">
    //Body here
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'unique'(aliases: uniq) filter in angular.filter module (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

usage: `colection | uniq: 'property'` 
you can filter by nested properties to : `colection | uniq: 'property.nested_property'`

So you can do something like that..

```
function MainController ($scope) {
 $scope.orders = [
  { id:1, customer: { name: 'foo', id: 10 } },
  { id:2, customer: { name: 'bar', id: 20 } },
  { id:3, customer: { name: 'foo', id: 10 } },
  { id:4, customer: { name: 'bar', id: 20 } },
  { id:5, customer: { name: 'baz', id: 30 } },
 ];
}
```

**HTML:** We filters by customer id, i.e remove duplicate customers

```
<th>All customers list: </th>
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | unique: 'customer.id'" >
   <td> {{ order.customer.name }} , {{ order.customer.id }} </td>
</tr>
```

**result:**
All customers list:
foo 10
bar 20
baz 30

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = [
    {
        _id: "500004",
        subject: "Complete the task",
        date: "25 Aug, 2013"
    },      
    {
        _id: "500004",
        subject: "Complete the task",
        date: "25 Aug, 2013"
    },      
    {
        _id: "500005",
        subject: "Attend to the event",
        date: "2 Jan, 2013"
    },      
    {
        _id: "500065",
        subject: "Some task deadline",
        date: "20 Sep, 2013"
    },      
    {
        _id: "500004",
        subject: "Complete the task",
        date: "25 Aug, 2013"
    }
]

var uniqueNames = [];
var uniqueObj = [];

for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    

    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(data[i]._id) === -1){
        uniqueObj.push(data[i])
        uniqueNames.push(data[i]._id);        
    }       

}

console.log('uniqueObj',uniqueObj)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C97DJ/165/