# Filtering ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Prior to updating Angular to 1.3, I was using Angular 1.2.

I was filtering my list of categories using this filter. What it does is remove a category that is a duplicate of what is passed in (me).

```
app.filter('CategorySelectFilter', function() {
    return function(cats, me) {
        var filteredCats = angular.copy(cats);
        for (var index in filteredCats) {
            if (me.id == filteredCats[index].id) {
                filteredCats.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        return filteredCats;
    };
});
```

Using this in my HTML, everything worked dandy.

```
ng-options="c as c.name for cat in filtered = (cats | CategorySelectFilter: cat) track by cat.id"
```

After updating to Angular 1.3, I started getting Infdig errors from this. I do not know what is happening.

EDIT: Added Plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/X2cAvRyd3pdjMDOOQKfI?p=preview

It seems to work fine in the Plnkr code, but still getting Infdig errors from the console. Try comparing the code from 1.2.13 and 1.3.13 of AngularJS.

1.3.13 throws a bunch of infdig errors.

Comment: Can you post a plnker?

Comment: So, you are trying to remove all the duplicates from the array?

Comment: I'm trying to put together a plnker, what I am doing is, I have a collection called cats, and I am using ng-repeat on it. Then I am going through each item in cats and giving it a list of ng-options which I remove itself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer provides some cool filters to look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747643/filter-unique-values-from-a-json). If you are doing a lot of filtering maybe its easy enough to import those libs.

[I created a fiddle to solve your issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/corn3lius/1m9bdy5y/6/)

or edited your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/AI1O9Z?p=preview

this is how to use it.

```
 ng-repeat="cat in cats | catFilter:'id' "
```

and the filter.

```
app.filter('catFilter', function() {
    return function(cats, key ) {
        return cats.filter( function(elem, index, array ) { 
            return ( array.map(function(item){return item[key];}).indexOf(elem[key]) === index );
        });

    };
});
```