# Angular JS filter on single value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is what I have tried:

```
<section data-ng-controller="HomeController">
<table ng-repeat="item in servers | unique:'_id.idc'">
<tr>
<td> {{ item._id.idc }} </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter:{_id.idc: 'LH5'}: true ">
  <td>{{data}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the current output:

```
LH8
LH5
AMS
```

If I remove the filter here is some sample from {{ data }}

```
{"_id":{"cluster":0,"idc":"LH8"},"Physical":{"SumCores":488,"SumMemory":3232},"Virtual":{"SumCores":2,"SumMemory":8}}
{"_id":{"cluster":1,"idc":"LH8"},"Physical":{"SumCores":256,"SumMemory":1024},"Virtual":{"SumCores":232,"SumMemory":469}}
```

Why is it not filtering correctly? unique works perfectly fine but the single filter does not.

**Edit:** I've also checked to see if the unique filter was somehow conflicting with it, but it still doesn't work without that filter in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is not formatted correctly for nested objects. It should be:

```
ng-repeat="data in servers | filter: { _id: { idc: 'LH5' } }"
```

A working, simplified example is below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
  
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.filter = 'red';
    $scope.cars = [
        {
            make: 'Ford',
            model: 'Focus',
            year: '2012',
            colors: {
             interior: 'red',
                exterior: 'blue'
            }
        },
        {
            make: 'Ford',
            model: 'Fusion',
            year: '2009',
            colors: {
             interior: 'green',
                exterior: 'black'
            }
        },
        {
            make: 'Honda',
            model: 'Civic',
            year: '2011',
            colors: {
             interior: 'red',
                exterior: 'silver'
            }
        }
    ]
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <label for="filter">Interior color filter: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filter" id="filter" />
    <div ng-repeat="car in cars | filter: { colors: { interior: filter } }">{{ car.year }} {{ car.make }} {{ car.model }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 25 of the expression [servers | filter: { _id { idc: 'LH5' } }] starting at [{ idc: 'LH5' } }].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=25&p3=servers%20%7C%20filter%3A%20%7B%20_id%20%7B%20idc%3A%20'LH5'%20%7D%20%7D&p4=%7B%20idc%3A%20'LH5'%20%7D%20%7D`

Comment: Fixed it!

`<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter: { _id: { idc: 'LH5' } }">`

Answer (score 0):

you add data first like

```
    <tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter:{data.idc : 'LH5'}">
      <td>{{data}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Also did not work I'm afraid - also this is syntactically incorrect, you are missing a "

Comment: try it now , i have changed it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use in your own way, you need to add one more JS file from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747643/filter-unique-values-from-a-json) for more detail

Comment: It is this bit which is not working: `filter:{_id.idc : 'LH5'}`

Answer (score 0):

From your example I assume your data structure looks something like this:

```
data: {
    propA: 'A',
    proB: 'B',
    _id: {
        idc: 'LH5'
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you are trying to get a match on a sub-property of the object(s) you are iterating over.

From the docs:

> Note that a named property will match properties on the same level
>   only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same
>   level or deeper. E.g. an array item like {name: {first: 'John', last:
>   'Doe'}} will not be matched by {name: 'John'}, but will be matched by
>   {$: 'John'}.

So I'd try:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter:{$: 'LH5'}: true ">
  <td>{{data}}</td>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kb598pby/

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering by nested attribute, the expression you passed to your filter does not evaluate to the valid javascript object. You should do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter:{_id: [{idc: 'LH5'}]}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the reference below

For filter single value in AngularJs

http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

I hope it can help you