# filter questions by checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am trying to filter test/question results by column headings.

This is a two-part question:

- How to filter row data using checkboxes
- How to use `unique` filter to ensure duplicate checkboxes are removed

**Part 1:**

For example, 4 questions here have associated categories and difficulties. If I click the `Perio` category, only rows of questions under the `Perio` category will be displayed. Likewise, I want to apply such filters for correctness and difficulty.

I thought using `| filter:category` or `| filter:difficulty` against the model would work, but it doesn't filter. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

**Checkboxes**:

```
        <div class="category-filter">
            <span class="heading">Filter</span>

            Categories
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions" class="question">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category"> {{q.question.cat_id}}</span>
            </div>

            Correct/Incorrect
            <div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="correct"> Correct</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="incorrect"> Incorrect</div>

            Difficulty
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions" class="question">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="difficulty"> {{q.question.difficulty}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Question row loops**:

```
        <div class="questions">
            <span class="heading">Question</span>
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:category" class="question" >
                <span ng-class="{correct: q.result == 'correct', incorrect: q.result == 'incorrect'}">{{q.question.id}}) {{q.question.question}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="question-category">
            <span class="heading">Category</span>
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:category " class="question">
                <span>{{q.question.cat_id}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="question-difficulty">
            <span class="heading">Difficulty</span>
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:difficulty" class="question">
                <span>{{q.question.difficulty}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Sample Data structure**:

```
                $scope.questions = [
                    {
                        question: {
                            id: 1,
                            question: 'Sit error corporis natus fugit eligendi quo assumenda. Ipsum officia quia suscipit nemo et.',
                            question_time: '1:10',
                            cat_id: 'Perio',
                            difficulty: 'easy'
                        },
                        result: 'correct',
                        user : 1
                    },
                    {
                        question: {
                            id: 2,
                            question: 'Jibber jabber jib jab sit error corporis natus fugit eligendi quo assumenda. Ipsum officia quia suscipit nemo et.',
                            question_time: '1:25',
                            cat_id: 'XRay',
                            difficulty: 'medium'
                        },
                        result: 'incorrect',
                        user : 1
                    },
                    {
                        question: {
                            id: 3,
                            question: 'Yabber jibber jabber jib jab sit error corporis natus fugit eligendi quo assumenda. Ipsum officia quia suscipit nemo et.',
                            question_time: '2:30',
                            cat_id: 'Perio',
                            difficulty: 'easy'
                        },
                        result: 'incorrect',
                        user : 1
                    },
                    {
                        question: {
                            id: 4,
                            question: 'Cool dude jabber jib jab sit error corporis natus fugit eligendi quo assumenda. Ipsum officia quia suscipit nemo et.',
                            question_time: '3:10',
                            cat_id: 'Teeth Stuff',
                            difficulty: 'hard'
                        },
                        result: 'correct',
                        user : 1
                    }
                ];
```

---

**Part 2: unique filter**

I tried using the [Angular Unique Filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js), as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747643/filter-unique-values-from-a-json), but it's not filtering out the unique categories. Instead, it is showing only the `Perio` category. What it should do is only filter out the redundant `Perio` category, and show only unique categories.

```
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions | unique:'q.question.cat_id'" class="question">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category"> {{q.question.cat_id}}</span>
            </div>
```

So far, I've only seen `unique` used with `ngOptions` and `<select>`, but I don't want to use `select`, but instead use checkboxes.

Comment: remember that `filter:'someValue'` works on all top level properties in the object.. so if search  is "1" and it finds that in `question` or in `difficulty` or in any other property value it will be shown. When you want specific property values only to match you need to pass object to `filter: {cat_id: categorySearchModelValue}`